# PyQt load database in tableview

Tags: database, pyqt, pyqt5, blob, qtsql

I have some issues with loading correctly databases in a tableview in my pyqt ui. The problem is that these specific databases have column that contains BLOB data and they are not displayed correctly in tableview.
Opening the same database with sqlitebrowser for windows displays the items of the blob column as a text field with multiple values(double clicking it reveals all), while in my tableview it only displays the first letter of the the first item.
[image: tableview]
Any way to replicate the sqlitebrowser software and display the blob correctly and display items as a dropdown with full values?
[image: sqlitebrowser]

this is the code I use for loading the database:

```py
def loadevents(self, str):
        db = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QSQLITE')
        db.setDatabaseName(str)
        db.open()
        print('database is '+str)
        projectModel = QtSql.QSqlQueryModel()
        projectModel.setQuery("SELECT  * FROM tblEvents")
        self.tableWidget.setModel(projectModel)
        self.tableWidget.show()
```

As described I would like that the last column that is of BLOB type(detail) to be loaded correctly (all text) and if possibily to display allsub items of each items in detail column as a dropdown list. 
ex: in sqlitebrowser doubleclicking "Updated completed successfully..." reveals multiple values.

Thanks in advance.

LE:
modified code:

```py
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableView(self.tab_3)
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 13, 1000, 800))
        self.tableWidget.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(1000, 800))
        self.tableWidget.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(1000, 800))
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
```

is part of a function of a class called Ui_MainWindow(object) - basicaly the class we instantiate for the window

in the same class I have another function that populates the tableview:

```py
def loadevents(self, str):
        db = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QSQLITE')
        db.setDatabaseName(str)
        db.open()
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)
        delegate = BlobDelegate(self.tableWidget)
        self.tableWidget.setItemDelegateForColumn(4, delegate)
        model = QtSql.QSqlQueryModel()
        model.setQuery("SELECT  * FROM tblTransEvents")
        self.tableWidget.setModel(model)
        self.tableWidget.show()
```

and it looks like this:
[image: newtableview]

Comment: Can you share your .db?

Comment: added the code. sorry

Comment: I see that the output is correct, I assume you are using another db, the problem is that your view shows all the data and not just one as the image shows in my answer?

Comment: Yes. I would like the first text, because it is the most important. at best would like to add the rest as a tooltip

Comment: Are only those lines in your code that modify the QTableView? When you try my code without modifying it, do you get the same?

Comment: try with my update: add `self.tableWidget.setWordWrap(True)
    self.tableWidget.setTextElideMode(QtCore.Qt.ElideLeft)`

Comment: doesn't make any difference. thanks anyway. it's impossible to addapt my code to yours as it contains many more methods and ui items. I'll figure it out. thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194438/discussion-between-erma86-and-eyllanesc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must implement a delegate that decodes the Blob data:

```py
import os
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtSql


class BlobDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def displayText(self, value, locale):
        if isinstance(value, QtCore.QByteArray):
            value = value.data().decode()
        return super(BlobDelegate, self).displayText(value, locale)


def createConnection():
    db = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QSQLITE")
    file = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), "db.db")
    db.setDatabaseName(file)
    if not db.open():
        QtWidgets.QMessageBox.critical(
            None,
            QtWidgets.qApp.tr("Cannot open database"),
            QtWidgets.qApp.tr(
                "Unable to establish a database connection.\n"
                "This example needs SQLite support. Please read "
                "the Qt SQL driver documentation for information "
                "how to build it.\n\n"
                "Click Cancel to exit."
            ),
            QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Cancel,
        )
        return False
    return True


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    if not createConnection():
        sys.exit(-1)

    w = QtWidgets.QTableView()
    w.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)
    w.setWordWrap(True)
    w.setTextElideMode(QtCore.Qt.ElideLeft)
    delegate = BlobDelegate(w)
    w.setItemDelegateForColumn(4, delegate)
    model = QtSql.QSqlQueryModel()
    model.setQuery("SELECT * FROM tblEvents")
    w.setModel(model)
    w.resize(640, 480)
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: I adapted to my code but details colum is a mess. the blob is decoded but it shows something else, not the first line

Comment: edited the question . PyQt is 5.12.1 , Python 3.7.2. For me details looks like it's trying to fit all the content decoded there,instead of displaying the primary sentence.